# VB.Net application halted while printing crystal report in client environment

Tags: vb.net, printing, crystal-reports

I am currently developing a vb.net application in VS 2005, with crystal report XI. I have come across a a problem where my application halted while printing reports. There is no error in my application, it's just that I can't click on any part/menu in the application while printing. The user opens the printing window form from the menu item, the form opens, he clicks on the 'print' button and it will print directly to his printer without preview. After a successful printing session, a text message box will display 'Printing success!'. Only then the user can continue click on other part/menu of the application. It would be troublesome during printing a large number pages of report, because the user have to wait all the pages finished printing only then they can continue to click on other menu of the system. Fro example, when I execute the printing window form (let's say form A), other posting form (Form B) becomes freeze. Below is my code for calling the report and directly printing to their printer.

[my code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGOjy.png)

I have to use simplex and duplex because the users requested the reports to be one-sided pages. My question is how to allow users to click on other menu/doing other posting with the system while printing those large number pages of reports?

Thanks for any help/input.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out what I wanted was a [background worker](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-ab&q=background%20process%20vb.net&oq=background%20process%20vb.net&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30k1l3j0i22i10i30k1j0i22i30k1.8838.9974.0.10341.7.7.0.0.0.0.120.715.3j4.7.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.7.712...0i67k1.0.YAi84BbIVQk)